# pymysql transaction saves one insert query but ignores two update queries without raising an error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Basically I'm trying to set up the save method of a PyQt5 form with a pymysql transaction. The save implies one insert query for a new record, and two updates which are a consequence of the insert. The method runs smoothly, but the two tables that are to be updated remain unchanged. There is no error raised and the insert does work.

Originally y tried to use SqlDatabase to establish the transactions but I was unable to set it up. It seems it requires to develop a driver for MySQL or maybe there already is one but couldn't find it. Any advise on this regard would be greatly appreciated.

```
def saveAndClose(self):
    """Requires to:
    - Save (Insert) new record in mortality table.
    - Update agreementhorses table - (active = False)
    - Update horses table - (active = False).
    - Refresh the dockMortality query in the main form.
    - Refresh this form horse query.
    """
    try:
         cnn = pymysql.connect(**self.con_string)
         cnn.begin()
         with cnn.cursor() as cur:
             sql_mortality = """ INSERT INTO mortality
                 (dod, agreementhorseid, causeid, diagnose, veterinaryid, 
                  notes)
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
             self.comboVet.setModelColumn(0)
             self.comboCause.setModelColumn(0)
             parameters = (self.dateOfDeath.date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                           self.record.value(8),
                           self.comboCause.currentText(),
                           self.lineDiagnosis.text(),
                           self.comboVet.currentText(),
                           self.textNotes.toPlainText())
             cur.execute(sql_mortality, parameters)
             sql_horses = """ UPDATE horses 
                 SET active = False
                 WHERE id = %s"""
             cur.execute(sql_horses, (self.record.value(8)),)
             sql_agreementhorses = """ UPDATE agreementhorses
                 SET active = False 
                 WHERE id = %s"""
             cur.execute(sql_agreementhorses, (self.record.value(9),))
             cnn.commit()
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        QMessageBox.Warning("saveAndClose", (type(e).__name__, e.args))
        cnn.rollback()
    except AttributeError as err:
        print(err.args)
        cnn.rollback()
    except Exception as err:
        print(type(err).__name__, err.args)
        cnn.rollback()
    finally:
        self.comboVet.setModelColumn(1)
        self.comboCause.setModelColumn(1)
        """Resets the  active horses list for this particular agreement"""
        self.tableHorses.model().setQuery(self.getHorsesQuery())
        """Resets the mortality list for this particular agreement on
           the main form subform"""          

        self.parent.tableMortality.model().\
            setQuery(self.parent.queryMortality())
        """Clear the form for the next record to be entered"""
        self.clearForm()
```

I expect the transaction to perform properly, inserting into one table and updating the other two. In the meantime I will try to establish the transaction with MySql.connector as a new try.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction works just fine. I made a mistake placing the parameters of the update queries. I placed the first query as parameter as the second one and vice versa. I took me some time to figure that out. I apologize to everyone trying to figure out my nonexistent issue. In short "self.record.value(8)" should have been "self.record.value(9)" and vice versa.